# Cancelar redirecionamento no envio de um formulário

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Como posso fazer com que nada seja mudado após o envio ajax, a página ficar no mesmo lugar e não ser carregada de novo?

script

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-carro').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'insert.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('.form-carro').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('.recebeDados').html (data);
            }          
        });
        return-false
    });
});
```

teria apenas que tirar o `success`?

Comment: Olá Pedro, a tua pergunta está pouco clara. Tens um erro de sintaxe `` `return-false` que podes simnplesmente remover, e imagino que precises de `$('.form-carro').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault();` para impedir que o formulário recarregue a página. É isso?

Comment: Boa, deu certo, apenas tirei o `return-false` e troquei o `$('.form-carro').submit(function(){` pelo `$('.form-carro').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault();`, muito obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para impedires um formulário de ser submetido tens de parár o evento `submit`. A maneira que o JavaScript nos dá é chamando `e.preventDefault();` dentro da callback do evento. Assim tens de fazer:

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-carro').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // ...etc
```

Repara também que tens um erro de sintaxe aqui: `return-false`. Na verdade essa linha que deveria ser `return false;` nem é necessária e podes remover.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está enviando os dados via Ajax, você não precisaria do submit (nem do elemento -  - nem do evento = $('.form-carro').submit())...

Você poderia modificar seu código da seguinte forma:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.form-carro').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.recebeDados').html (data);
        }          
    });
});
```

No máximo, caso seu código esteja em um button, você teria que receber um event como parâmetro da função onclick e adicionar logo no início dela uma chamada à função preventDefault:

```
event.preventDefault()
```